# problems in pentaho demo apps

Tags: pentaho

i get demo application from net for pentaho application...it shows some error on home.jsp
like

```
  Could not generate chart image.
Could not load chart data from samples/steel-wheels/homeDashboard/Sales_by_Territory.xaction

    Could not generate chart image.
Could not load chart data from samples/steel-wheels/homeDashboard/Sales_by_Productline.xaction
```

what is the problem
anybody know what is the problem is there  and how can i solve that

Comment: @Mr.Kandhasamy: can u elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

The data for the samples should be loaded in with the demo application's in-memory database system.  Typically, you'll see this error because the Hypersonic database isn't turned on, or if you've been trying to switch the demo server over to another database engine, something went wrong with that process.